# AzureCredentials not found in Azure .Net SDK

Tags: azure, active-directory

I must be missing something silly. I'm trying to authenticate my server backup app to have access to my Azure account so I can do things like programmatically create storage accounts, etc. If I understand right, you have to create a service principal. I think I got that taken care of, now I just need to add the code:

```
  AzureCredentials credentials = AzureCredentials.FromServicePrincipal(client, key, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
  Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

Problem is references for "AzureCredentials" and "Azure", or "IAzure" all can't be found. I've installed the Azure SDK, added references as follows:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Authentication;
```

...nothing! What am I missing?

**EDIT:** The suggested package in the answer below was correct, except the "Azure" reference still can't be found. I believe it is in "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent", but when I try to add it, I'm getting this:

> Failed to add reference. The package 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.Xml.XDocument' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.         0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent` sdk  and refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.authentication.azurecredentialsfactory.fromserviceprincipal?view=azuremgmtresourcemanager-fluent-1.0.0#Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_Authentication_AzureCredentialsFactory_FromServicePrincipal_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_ResourceManager_Fluent_AzureEnvironment_) , you could try below code to login with ServicePrincipal :

```
AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(...)
```

OR

```
var credentials = new AzureCredentials(new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation { ClientId = "xxxxxx", ClientSecret = "xxxxx" }, "tenantid", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
```

Comment: Wow.....thank you! I looked over the whole world wide web and couldn't find that anywhere. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Well, I thought I was good. Now I have a reference to AzureCredentials, but I really need to the reference to "Azure", which I believe is in "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent". Unfortunately, I get the error above (see my edit).

Comment: I finally got it working. Visual Studio can be so unhelpful at times. I pretty much had to install the packages on another development machine then push the changes to source control....